# ecryptfs-migrate-home with domain user's home directory

Tags: authentication, ecryptfs

Shortly, we have a windows AD Domain. We have lots of Ubuntu Clients with 18.04, currently, we want to encrypt those user's home directories.

Our issue is when ecryptfs asks user's password even if we entered correct, it says wrong password. 
When our users log-in their devices, they authenticate via LDAP. There is no issue about it. But Ecryptfs-migrate-home doesn't work with it. 
Any suggestion?